# can coq intros pattern split at the rightmost opportunity for conjunction?

Tags: coq

I am wondering if there is some intro pattern which can introduce
`A /\ B /\ C` as

```
H1: A /\ B
H2: C
```

I'm aware that  `intros [H1 H2]` will produce

```
H1: A
H2: B /\ C
```

but cannot figure out how to configure the brackets for the other direction.
This is a trivial example; but I have a more complicated combination of conjunctions and disjunctions that I would much prefer to destruct from right to left.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_ /\ _` notation in Coq is a right-associative *binary* operator, so `A /\ B /\ C` really stands for `A /\ (B /\ C)`. If you want to build some `A /\ B` you should first fully decompose the `/\` (`intros [HA [HB HC]].`, you can nest the patterns arbitrarily) and then build the `A /\ B` hypothesis (for instance using `assert (A /\ B) as HAB by (split ; [exact HA| exact HB]).` or any other way you prefer to add an hypothesis).

In a more complex setting, you might want to write a lemma `and_assoc : forall A B C, A /\ B /\ C -> (A /\ B) /\ C` and use a *view*-pattern. Starting from a goal
`A /\ B /\ C -> P` you can use `intros [HAB HC]%and_assoc.` to obtain `HAB : A /\ B` and `HC : C` : the `pat%and_assoc` part says that `and_assoc` should be applied first to the top assumption and then further destructed with `pat`.

Comment: You should also be able to replace `[HA [HB HC]]` with `(HA & HB & HC)`, if you like that better.